# Dihedral group $D_4$ (symmetries of a square) is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_4$ (permutation group)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I have this problem that I have been stuck on for a while. I know that I can write the elements of $D_4$ as products of the identity, rotation by $90$ degrees and a vertical reflection and I have already written the $8$ elements of $D_4$ as their cycle notation is $S_4$ but have no idea what to do from there and would really appreciate the help!

Comment: That is not true since $\;|D_4|=8 \;$ , yet $\;|S_4|=4!=24\;$

Comment: Did you mean "show $D_4$ is a subgroup of $S_4$"?

Comment: D4 does not mix the pairing of opposing vertices, and you need three possible such pairings to define all permutatiins of S4.  So D4 is isomorphic with only one-third of S4.

Comment: Super sorry! Meant to write subgroup and have edited the title appropriately

Comment: I fear I don't fully follow the answer, particularly could you explain it specifically for n=4?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Label the corners of a square. Permute them.

Comment: So I have done that and got a set of cycles. But I was wondering if there is an easy way to show that the cycles you get that are generated by the permutations is a subgroup

Comment: Did you happen to have any other hints? I'm not sure what to do with this

Comment: Here's another hint, @user690808: Any subset of a group $G$ that is a group under the operation of $G$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Yes so when I write all the permutations of a square as cycles. I get 8 cycles but is there a way to show that this is closed under composition without writing them all out? Or is there a smarter way to show that there is a subgroup than manually finding the equivalent cycles and then mapping a isomorphism

Comment: If you had any other insight that would be very appreciated!

Comment: Another hint, @user690808, is that $$D_4\cong \langle g,h\mid g^4, h^2, hgh^{-1}=g^{-1}\rangle,$$ and note that it suffices to work with generators and what they map to.

Comment: So I think what I am struggling with is not representing D4 but proving that the cycles in S4 that I would like to show are isomorphic to D4 are a subgroup of S4

Comment: Essentially I already know $D_4=\{e,(1234),(13)(24),(1432),(14)(23),(42),(13),(12)(34)\}$.

Comment: I suggest, then, @user690808, that you use either the one-step or two-step [subgroup tests](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test).

Comment: Would I then have to list out all 64 combinations to check this?

Comment: Not if you work with the generators, you don't, @user690808.

Comment: How would that work? I'm not sure we have covered anything along those lines yet

Comment: My professor has said that I've implicitly defined a function from D4-> Sn ie chosen some element in D4 and chosen a permutation that follows. What can I say about this function?